# sys.stdout.write refreshing output problem

Tags: python, console-application, stdout

While refreshing outputs, the old written data on terminal won't disappear.

- VS Code Version: 1.37.1
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

```py
from ipaddress import ip_address
import sys
import time

def ips(start, end):
    start_int = int(ip_address(start).packed.hex(), 16)
    end_int = int(ip_address(end).packed.hex(), 16)
    return [ip_address(ip).exploded for ip in range(start_int, end_int)]

tmpList = (ips("192.168.1.254", "192.168.2.2"))

for ip in tmpList:
    sys.stdout.write(f"\r{ip}")
    time.sleep(2)
```

The final result is:

```
192.168.2.155
```

Yet the printed list doesn't contain such data:

```
[192.168.1.254, 192.168.1.255, 192.168.2.0, 192.168.2.1]
```

Last "55"s is from 192.168.1.255, shouldn't it be gone or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the carriage return character doesn't delete the current line, but instead moves the cursor to the start and begins printing. If your second string is smaller than your first string, then the end of the first string will still end up being displayed after the second string has printed.

To ensure every string you print is the same length, you can use the [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) method to left-justify your string. You can pass the width of the string you want to `ljust` to automatically format it correctly. Optionally, `str.ljust` also accepts another argument, `fillchar` which is the character to fill the extra spaces in the string with. The default is a space. For example, `"hello".ljust(10, "x")` will return `"helloxxxxx"`.

A width of 20 characters is more than enough space for standard IPv4 addresses.

Applying this to your code is easy:

```py
from ipaddress import ip_address
import sys
import time

def ips(start, end):
    start_int = int(ip_address(start).packed.hex(), 16)
    end_int = int(ip_address(end).packed.hex(), 16)
    return [ip_address(ip).exploded for ip in range(start_int, end_int)]

tmpList = (ips("192.168.1.254", "192.168.2.2"))

for ip in tmpList:
    sys.stdout.write(f"\r{ip}".ljust(20)) # <--- Added call to ljust here
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I think your answer is better than mine. I was assuming the line could be an arbitrary length (e.g. multiple IP-addresses), but for showing only one IP address this is a nicer solution. And I think your explanation is very clear. This answer deserves my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

If you (temporarily) remove the "\r" character (= carriage return) by "\n" (= new line), you'll see the following output:

```
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.255
192.168.2.0
192.168.2.1
```

If you use a carriage return, the previous line is not automatically removed, but you just printed over it. In this case, the "55" is still on the screen because it was printed earlier and it has not been overwritten yet.

**Solution:**

A possible solution is to remember the length of the previous line, and when the next line is shorter, write the required number of spaces after the line to "erase" the previous content.

**Example:**

You could do something like this (putting it in a class instead of using globals is better, but I'd like to keep the example short):

```py
# instead of the last 3 lines of your code end like this:

previous_line_length = 0
def update_line(line):
    global previous_line_length
    required_spaces = max(0, previous_line_length - len(line))
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + line + required_spaces * ' ')
    previous_line_length = len(line)

for ip in tmpList:
    update_line(ip)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is a great answer as well. I'm not sure why it was down-voted but my vote brought it back up to 0